# How to run Scala project on local Apache - Windows

Tags: windows, scala, apache, playframework, sbt

I received a Scala project to be run locally.
I'm on Windows, I've installed MySql (needed by the project), Apache 2.4 configured and started on port 9000 as suggested on Play Framework website, installed `sbt` and `scala`.

Now.. I got lost.. I don't understand how am I supposed to publish/deploy the project locally?
Which directory is supposed to be the www Apache directory? 
How am I supposed to tell `sbt` that I'm running Apache? 
I cant find any hint around.

Any structured suggestion to help my nut crawling on a bit?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not an Apache expert. Could you provide some details how it is intended to be used - is this an reverse proxy or sort of application container (like Tomcat)?

Comment: play framework does not need apache, it has its own build-in server that can serve requests. Apache/nginx could be useful if you need proxy or additional ssl configuration but this is rather prodution problem. You should be able to run play framework app using `sbt run` like Rayan suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that would be helpful, but you've mentioned `play framework`. If your project is made with `play`, you should be able just to execute `sbt run` in your project directory, and then your application should be accessible via http://localhost:9000.
Details here: https://www.playframework.com/getting-started